# Publish comment without refreshing the page using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Textarea form submitting the data to the server but it isn't display the comment without refreshing the page

Here is the Script:

```
$("#post_reply").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();   
    if(document.getElementById('_comment').value.trim()==""){
        return false;
    }
    $.post( '../services/leave_comment.php', $("#open_status").serialize(),  
        function( data ) {  
            $('#ajax_loading').hide();
            if(data){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url : 'http://localhost/tech1/services/get_more_comments.php',  
                    data: 'last_id='+last_id,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.view_container').append(data);
                        $('.view_container_parent').load('get_more_comments.php');
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        console.log('DONE');
                    }                       
                });
            }
        });  
});
```

Here is the structure of html and view_container_parent has to be loaded without refreshing

```
<div class="comments" id="comments">
    <div class="comm_container">
        <div class="insert_container">
             <form class="commentform">
             <textarea>
             </form> 
        </div>
     </div>          
     <div class='view_container_parent'>//whole lot of comments
         <div class='view_container'>//single comment
         </div>
         <div class='view_container'>//single comment
         </div>
         <div class='view_container'>//single comment
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Help me please,,,,this has already eaten my 3days.

Comment: have you tried `html()` to put the content ?

Comment: In chrome, right click, inspect element, click the network tab. Are the requests being sent to the server and the data coming back as expected?

Comment: `html()` use for replace all html inside parent. He's just wanna get new data from `last_id` and append it to `view_container_parent`

Comment: Why do you need to do `$('.view_container_parent').load('get_more_comments.php');`? It's confusing... because you just append some content then you kinda overwrite it.

Comment: @Gnijuohz He need load only new comment from `last_id`. Load all is bad for load many comment items.

Comment: @Louis.CLast okay, so i can append only the newcomment without load the complete parent??

Comment: @Fastnto yes, of course. Make sure `leave_comment.php` response correct as true then the ajax `get_more_comments.php` will run. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#post_reply").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();   
    if(document.getElementById('_comment').value.trim()==""){
            return false;
    }
    $.post('../services/leave_comment.php', $("#open_status").serialize(),  
        function(data) {  
            $('#ajax_loading').hide();
            if(data){
                $('#ajax_loading').show();
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost/tech1/services/get_more_comments.php',  
                data: 'last_id='+last_id,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#ajax_loading').hide();
                    console.log('AJAX SUCCESS');
                    $('.view_container_parent').append(data);
                    console.log('Append data');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    console.log('DONE');
                }                
                });
            }
        } 
    );  
});
```

Your response must be (loop):

```
<div class="view_container">
...
</div>
```

Your HTML only need:

```
<div class="view_container_parent">
    <div class="view_container">
        <!-- Another comment before -->
    </div>
    <!-- The ajax will append data from here -->
</div>
```

You can test your response data with `console.log(data)`

Comment: Yep, I think append should be used on class `view_container_parent`. If only want new comment to appear, I think there is no need to make another ajax call

Comment: I don't know about post request of `../services/leave_comment.php`. I think it used for submit textarea, if the submit is success then the ajax below will work and append new comment.

Comment: `leave_comment.php` is to insert the record in the database